# Why does server show old ASPX page (even if deleted)?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

When I upload a new .aspx file, the server continues showing the old version.

What I've tried:

1. Forced page refresh: Control+R or Control+F5
2. Deleted the file on the
   server & refreshed page.

Expected result: new page shown (or 404 error when page deleted)

Actual result: old page dhown.

**Repro steps:**

1. View https://www.bungalowsoftware.com/subscription/info/default.aspx
2. The START NOW button shows a link to .../create.aspx
3. View in File Manager and that button shows link to /buy
4. RENAME$ /default.aspx to something else (default.disabled.aspx, etc.)
5. Browse to the site again. Should give a 404, but still shows page.
6. This is happening with every aspx page I've tested.
7. Note: if I update or add plain .html files* the new versions show up immediately through the browser.

*in the same directory as the .aspx page I'm testing.

Comment: You need to do a re-start of IIS in many cases. And with a hosted solution, you often can't do that. From the command line, this: c:\> iisreset /restart   (as noted, you often can't do this, and thus you are at the mercy of the web server. You could also check the date/time stamp on the page(s) you up-load. Often due to UTC, the times are off set by 7 hours - and thus the server will not see the updated page.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the cache issue you could follow the below steps:

1)Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.

2)In the Connections pane, go to the site for which you want to disable caching.

3)From the middle pane, double-click HTTP Response Headers.

[image]

4)In the HTTP Response Headers pane, click Set Common Headers... in the Actions pane.

5)In the Set Common HTTP Response Headers dialog box, check the box to expire Web content, select Immediately, and then click OK.

[image]

Note: After making changes to the iis site folders or pages do not forget to restart iis server or site.